# in html how to find the similar shade for red color of a green color

Tags: html, colors

I have a color 94,131,38 (R,G,B) #5e8326. Its a green shaded color. I want the similar shade in red.

I dont know how to do it. I tried 131,94,38 (R,G,B). Is it like that.

Comment: Describe what is "similar shade" ?

Comment: after going through the answer below. In the site colorhexa.com, i found teradic color. i think that is what i am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great website for finding colors is http://www.colorhexa.com/
I use it all the time for web development.

The site will give you complementary colors and also similar shades.

The triadic colors in this example would give you a red color of #83265e.

[image]

The websafe color can be found as the last thing in the colors description.

[image]

Comment: i have gone in that site, what is websafe color

Comment: The site will list the closest websafe color, in this case for the red it is #993366.

Comment: how did you get it for #5e8326 the websafe color of red is #993366. I mean i type #5e8326 in the search and enter. after that how you get the #993366 in the page

Comment: Scroll down to where you see the traidic colors, then click on the red one. Once there, in the description of the color it will show you the closest websafe color. I edited my answer to show you.

Comment: It's really not any better now days, use whatever colors you want. :P, if you want more information on why you can check out this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041113/are-web-safe-colors-still-relevant

Comment: yes then i will use the corresponding tetradic color. thank you